# Spring Cloud Netflix: Will Eureka client prefer to choose the remote service in same zone?

Tags: netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

The [document](https://github.com/Netflix/eureka/wiki/Understanding-Eureka-Peer-to-Peer-Communication) says:

> Eureka clients tries to talk to Eureka Server in the same zone. If there are problems talking with the server or if the server does not exist in the same zone, the clients fail over to the servers in the other zones.

So I know clients will query servers at the same zone first. But my question is will clients prefer to choose the remote service at the same zone? Different zones could be mapped to different server rooms so RPC across to another zone may bring more network latency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same zone first, the load balancing is done using Ribbon.
http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#_using_ribbon_with_eureka

> By default it will be used to locate a server in the same zone as the
>   client because the default is a `ZonePreferenceServerListFilter`.